# Argument 'open' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DataFrame)

Tags: python, stock

```
tickers = ['HDFCBANK.NS' , 'VOLTAS.NS']
screen = yfinance.download(tickers , period='1d', interval='5m')
print(screen)

morning_star = talib.CDLMORNINGSTAR(screen['Open'], screen['High'] , screen['Low'] , screen['Close'])
morning_star
```

how to get through with this error and add more stocks

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a **data frame instead of an array** in `screen['Open']` parameter.

In the line,

`morning_star = talib.CDLMORNINGSTAR(screen['Open'], screen['High'] , screen['Low'] , screen['Close'])`

So, try **converting** `screen['Open']` **it to series and then to array**, then this will solve your issue.

Below is the documentation for the function that you are having issue with. Refer this link [here](https://cryptotrader.org/talib).

**CDLMORNINGSTAR - Morning Star**
`talib.CDLMORNINGSTAR(params)`

**Input parameters:**

open - array of floats

high - array of floats

low - array of floats

close - array of floats

startIdx - start index for input data

endIdx - end index for input data

optInPenetration